# I can't upgrade WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I transferred a 10 websites from one to another server. All sites use WordPress.
When i tried to upgrade to WordPress 3.8.3 using update now link on the dashboard I am getting this error message.

```
Downloading update from https://downloads.wordpress.org/release/sr_RS/wordpress-3.8.3.zip…

Download failed.: Operation timed out after 300000 milliseconds with 523957 out of 6327138 bytes received

Installation Failed
```

Plugin Update works fine. WordPress just will not update.
At all sites the same error.

On the old server it works fine. On the new server everything works except the update WordPress.

Comment: Have you tried ssh'ing into the server and downloading that file on the command line? Is it still just as slow to download?

Comment: No I have not tried over SSH. 
I'm not gud with Putty, i all working through Cpanel.
Which command to use to try download via SSH. Tnx

Comment: My first choice would be `wget`, it even has an ASCII art progress indicator so you can check the speed easily.

Comment: I tried, is going slow ... 15.6k / s 
Average time to download update is 6 minutes.

Comment: Well, that would be your problem. Either your internet connection or wordpress.org is being slow. Too slow. Are downloads from other servers slow as well? This is veering off topic though as a slow internet connection isn't that much of a programming-related problem.

Comment: Other server is faster... average time to download update iz 10 sec.

Comment: where can set to 300000 milliseconds is 500000.
That would be enough time to download 6 MB. 
Well now that I wrote Hetzner, to solve the problem with the internet speed to the server. Tnx...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your connection is slow, you can temporarily edit the file /wp-admin/includes/file.php. Search for the function `function download_url( $url, $timeout = 300 )` and replace 300 with a larger number, e.g 3000. The file will be replaced after the WordPress has been updated.

Comment: `The file will be replaced after the WordPress has been updated.` - Not necessarily, WP only updates files from the core that have been changed. That's whey they also have the re-install button, so that a whole new version can be downloaded if necessary.